# web browser: how to invoke android app QR code scanner to get scanned results

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, qr-code

**Web browser:** How can I invoke android app QR code scanner to get scanned results?

```
1. click a link in web page
2. open QR scanner app
3. web gets the scanned code.
```

**Can web get results from an Android native app?**

Answer (score 0):

You Need to explain more about your question, but i guess you need to open your QR Code app when user clicks on a link. So Try this in your app, and set a particular link to open your app

```html
 <activity
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:label="NAME"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true"
                android:label="App Name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="webpagelink.in"
                    android:path="/qrcode"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: This can open native app, but it can not get qr code back from native app to web, right?

Comment: Hey, can explain more , I am not able to understand it